# Double map insertion problem

Tags: c++, string, stl, dictionary, operator-overloading

I have an
stl::map that has the key defined as an object I defined, and int. The use of the map is as follows:
I have a list of the specific object and I want to count how many identical objects I have. So I insert the objects into the map.if the object already exists in the map I increase it's value (hence the counter). The object has all the basic operators defined. The object consist of 5 strings. The == operator defined as the comparison of all 5 strings, and logically is meaningfull in the context. The problem is that the operator < has no logic meaning in the context. I care only if the objects are equal. I can't define which of two different objects is bigger.so for the sake of stl map defined this operator as the result of if else ladder and in each if I compared with "<" another string of the five. If true return true else, if.... And the last else returns false. In a specific case of the object , where I had three identical instances, I got the map containing two identical objects as keys, one of them had the counter of 1 and the other had 2.
i can't understand what is the problem and how could it happen.
For those who requested some code examples - for reason i can't explain - i can't post the code itself, but i will write a good example of it(please ignore little things like missing ';' - i wrote it in 5 minutes):

```
class Example
{
private:
    string one;
    string two;
    string three;
    string four;
    string five;
public:
    inline Example (string a_one,string a_two, string a_four, string a_five) :
        one(a_one),two(a_two),three(a_three),four(a_four),five(a_five)
        {}

    inline bool operator == (const Example& other) const
    {
        if (one == other.one)
        {
            if (two == other.two)
            {
                if (three == other.three)
                {
                    if (four == other.four)
                    {
                        if (five == other.five)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    inline bool operator < (const Example& other) const
    {
        if (one < other.one)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (two < other.two)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (three < other.three)
        {
            return true ;
        }
        else if (four < other.four)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (five < other.five)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

void CountExample(Example& example,std::map<Example,int>& counters);

void main()
{
    std::map<Example,int> counters;
    std::list<Example> examples = GetExamples();
    //GetExamples defined elsewhere, and initializes examples with a long list of instances of Example
    std::list<Example>::const_iterator Iter;
    for (Iter = examples.begin();Iter != examples.end();Iter++)
    {
        CountExample(*Iter);
    }
    PrintCounters(counters);//PrintCounters defined elsewhere and prints the map to a file
}

void CountExample(Example& example,std::map<Example,int>& counters)
{
    std::map<Example,int>::const_iterator Iter;
    Iter = counters.find(example);
    if (Iter ==counters.end()) //means the specific Example is not in the map
    {
        counters.insert(std::pair<Example,int>(example,1));
    }
    else
    {
        counters[example] += 1;
    {
}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, please just post some actual code.

Comment: I really feel like linking to this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/106202/1850

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reasonably modern compiler, that ladder of comparisons can be replaced with a single comparison between two `std::tie()`'d tuples:

```
#include <tuple>
...
bool operator== (const Example& other) const
{
    return std::tie(one, two, three, four, five)
        == std::tie(other.one, other.two, other.three, other.four, other.five);
}
bool operator < (const Example& other) const
{
    return std::tie(one, two, three, four, five)
         < std::tie(other.one, other.two, other.three, other.four, other.five);
}
```

Incidentally, it may be simpler to use a `std::multiset` to count the number of times a particular element is stored in an associative container, that simplifies `CountExample` to a one-liner

```
void CountExample(const Example& example, std::multiset<Example>& counters)
{
    counters.insert(example);
}
```

Although printing becomes a bit more tricky:

```
void PrintCounters(const std::multiset<Example>& counters)
{
    for(auto i=counters.begin(); i!=counters.end(); i = counters.upper_bound(*i))
            std::cout << *i << ":" << counters.count(*i) << '\n';
}
```

Test on ideone: http://ideone.com/uA7ao

Comment: While `std::tie` can introduce lexicographical ordering for a struct/class, I don't believe it solves the problem with equality and weak-ordering ... for instance, as it's constructed right now, if `operator<` is false, then `!(A < B)` will be true, but that does not necessarily mean that A is greater than B ... it simply means that A is not less than B, but they could still be equal. So this still doesn't rule out the issue of establishing equality in weak-ordering, although it is a nice way to reorganize the code.

Comment: @Jason `operator<` for tuples takes all that into account. It is defined as `(std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs)) || (!(std::get<0>(rhs) < std::get<0>(lhs)) && lhstail < rhstail)`, where `lhstail` is `lhs` without its first element, and `rhstail` is `rhs` without its first element.

Answer (score 1):

To make a comparison with multiple elements, each element that you compare will have *three* outcomes: less than, greater than, or equivalent. You must account for all of these cases.

```
bool LessThan(const MyClass & left, const MyClass right)
{
    if (left.one < right.one)
        return true;
    else if (right.one < left.one)
        return false;
    // equivalent in one
    if (left.two < right.two)
        return true;
    else if (right.two < left.two)
        return false;
    // equivalent in one and two
        ...
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The nesting of the else without an if isn't required, and cuts out ~15 lines.

Comment: @Yoav, as I said you have 3 outcomes but a single comparison can only generate 2. Notice that `right < left` is the same as `left > right`, it might make more sense then.

Comment: @Yoav to elaborate further you only need to compare the less significant elements when the more significant ones are equal. When `left.x != right.x` the comparison is finished.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: After thinking about the problem some more, I've decided to removed my older answer since it did not seem pertinent to the current problem being experienced. Your `operator<` method does seem to be fulfilling the requirements for a strict weak ordering, so I think the problem lies somewhere else, and so I'm leaving the following alternate solution below ...*

It seem you're having issues creating a total order for your map, so you might want to look at `std::unordered_map` as an alternative that will directly apply your `operator==` for detecting equality, rather than using your `operator<` for a strict weak ordering ... you'll have to provide a hash-function for your class, but otherwise the use of the hash-table based `std::unordered_map` container is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: here is the shocker - i did think so(just as you explained) and added the exact line that you suggested. still - the duplicate is inserted

Comment: I think you mean equality is when `(A<B) ` and `(B<A)` are both false... I don't think `(A<B)` and `!(A<B)` can be both false at the same time, unless I seriously need to review my boolean logic.

Comment: @ jason: there is no sorting criteria for the inner strings. one has a different meaning from two and i cant really sort the data members of example. on the other hand i think that i understood from you that it doesn't matter and the only thing matters is that the results will be consistent. is that what you meant?

Comment: @Yoav R. : Yes, I'm saying that you need to-do something that establishes a total order for the map, and that requires a consistent rule for establishing whether objects are less than, equal to, or greater than each other. If you're saying that the different strings are completely separate entities, then you may need to only compare one of the strings and not all of them.

Comment: BTW, if you iterate through your map and find that the duplicates are not grouped together, then that is a definite indicator of a problem where there is some type of ambiguous element to the test for establishing the order of the elements similar to what I described in my update to this answer. It basically means that under one set of circumstances A < B will be true, but under another set of circumstances, such as a different insertion order or series of elements to compare against, B < A will be true, and of course that's not possible.

Comment: @Yoav R. Quick question: The strings order is important, correct?  For example `{ dog, cat, rat, mouse, trap }` would not be considered a "duplicate" of `{ cat, dog, rat, mouse, trap }` right?  If those are considered different sets, then do you have some place where I can get a copy of your code that also includes `GetExamples()` and `PrintCounters()` so I can re-generate your results?

Comment: @Yoav R. BTW, I tried a [quick run of your code here](http://www.ideone.com/kWuhe)... I didn't run into any issues. Do you have a data-set I can run this example code on and reproduce the same issues you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an `operator<` for you type.  This can be pretty tedious to write, but you can simply it by using a [`Boost.Tuple`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) - that way, the tuple handles the comparisons, leaving your code easier to read, write and understand.

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>
#include <string>

struct Object
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
};

bool operator<(const Object& obj1, const Object& obj2)
{
    return (boost::tie(obj1.a, obj1.b, obj1.c) < 
        boost::tie(obj2.a, obj2.b, obj2.c));
}
```

Comment: can't use boost....(actually i can, only if i prove to my manager that there is no easy solution without boost)

Comment: If you can use C++11 you can do it with `std::tie`...alternatively the same could be done by using nested `std::pair`s